# What shape a point with a constant distance along a parabola will trace?

Tags: calculus, geometry

1. Define a parabola where it's directrix will be a line over the Y axis and the focus point will be a point in the X axis. [Example parabola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L7Gz.png)
2. Define a distance n and grab a point D in the parabola where it's distance from the X axis along the parabola is equal to n. [Illustration of distance n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mChw.png)
3. Move the focus point along the X axis and keep the distance of point D constant (it will always have the same distance, along the parabola, from the X axis).

What shape will the point D trace?

Note: I have a suspicion it will be a line but I don't know how to prove it. Also this not my homework or work project so no need to hurry in answering it.

Comment: @ Gabriel Quintino: Arc length and position of point D are kept the same, by varying the parabola focal length, right?

Comment: Yes, the arc length is kept the same the X and Y coordinate of the point may vary because the parabola becomes "flatter" (see @heropup's answer) as the focus point change

Answer (score 0):

Let assume the focus at the point $F(f,0)$ then the equation of the parabola is

$$x=\frac1{4f}y^2+\frac f2$$

the vertex has coordinates $V(f/2,0)$ and we are looking for a point $D(x_D,y_D)$ on the parabola such that

$$n = \int_{0}^{y_D} \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} =\int_{0}^{y_D}\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^2+1\;} dy=\int_{0}^{y_D}\sqrt{\dfrac{y^2}{4f^2}+1\;} dy=$$

$$=\frac{y_D}4\sqrt{\frac{y_D^2}{f^2}+4}+f\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac {y_D}{2f}\right)$$

which can be solved numerically for any fixed $n$ and $f$ to find $y_D$ and then finding $x_D$ from the equation of the parabola.

The solution seems far to be a line.

---

A solution in closed form can be obtained for the simpler problem with a fixed distance from the vertex of the parabola. In this case we have

$$\left(x_D-\frac f2\right)^2+y_D^2=n^2$$

which using the equation of the parabola leads to

$$\left(x_D-\frac f2\right)^2+4fx_D-2f^2-n^2=0$$

which leads to (taking the positive solution)

$$x_D=\sqrt{4f^2+n^2}-\frac 32 f$$

and then

$$y_D =\sqrt{4f\sqrt{4f^2+n^2}-8 f^2}$$

which can be plotted for any fixed $n>0$ assuming $f$ as a parameter.

Note that in this case for $f\gg n$ we have

$$\sqrt{4f^2+n^2}=2f \left(1+\frac {n^2} {4f^2}\right)\approx 2f+\frac {n^2} {4f}\implies x_D\approx \frac f2+\frac {n^2} {4f}\; \land \; y_D \approx n $$

Here is a plot for a fixed $n=1$ and $0\le f \le 5$

[image]

Also in this simpler case, the solution seems far to be a line.

Comment: I don't see where you have you taken the distance "along the (arc of) parabola" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Indeed I’ve taken the distance from the vertex. I’ve misunderstood the question. I try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @JeanMarie In this way the problem becomes very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we would need to do is compute the arclength function of a parabola with a fixed vertex (labeled $H$ in the diagram) and a variable focus $C$.  To this end, it is more convenient to transform the coordinate system to place the vertex at $(0,c/2)$ and the focus at $(0,c)$.  Then the parabola has equation
$$y = \frac{x^2}{2c} + \frac{c}{2}.$$
Hence the arclength from $x = 0$ to $x = k$ is
$$S(k) = \int_{x=0}^k \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^k \sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{c^2}} \, dx = \frac{k \sqrt{c^2+k^2}}{2 c}-\frac{1}{2} c \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2+k^2}-k}{c}\right).$$
So if $S(k) = n$, we require the $x$-coordinate of the point on the parabola to be
$$k = S^{-1}(n)$$
and we wish to trace the locus of $$\left(S^{-1}(n), \frac{(S^{-1}(n))^2}{2c} + \frac{c}{2}\right)$$ for $c > 0$.  Clearly such a locus has no elementary closed form expression, so we resort to numerical methods.  A plot for $n \in \{0.1, 0.5, 1, 2\}$ is shown below:
[image]

The upward behavior of the curve arises from the fact that for large values of $c$ relative to $n$, the parabola has "flattened out" and is moving upward at a rate of $c/2$.  So in this regime, the locus will approximate the line $x = n$.  But for $c$ very small relative to $n$, the arclength along the parabola will be close to the parabola's axis, and the locus will tend toward the point $(0,n)$.  The interesting behavior occurs in the transition between these two regimes when $c$ and $n$ are roughly the same.